# Correct spelling of "can too" in response to "you can't"

Tags: grammar, colloquialisms

If someone says "you can't do that" there's a colloquial response of "can too". Is it "can too" or "can to"?

Comment: Possible duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

The appropriate phrase would be 'can too'. This one I'm going to have to go on process of elimination because 'can to' doesn't make any grammatical sense, be it colloquial or otherwise.

One would think that the use of 'too' in that phrase came from one of its meanings:

> as well: used to indicate that a person, thing, or aspect of a situation applies in addition to the one just mentioned

But we're not exactly expressing one's ability to do something 'as well'. Rather, we're negating the previous person's assertion that we cannot do it. Regardless, the answer is 'can too'.